# Method with 3 parameters but accepting one?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

Is there a way to make Method that takes 3 or more parameters but can accept 1?

```
public void getAllSongs(String one, String two, String Three){
dosomething
}
getAllSongs("tada");
```

maybe not the best way to explain but i dont how else.
I want use the same method with in more ways..
is it even possible?

Comment: Are you thinking of something along the lines of [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)? The alternative is method overloading.

Comment: You can use arrays to use only one function --> see my post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO.
But its possible in C++/C# (assign parameters with a default values)
Eg. :

```
public void getAllSongs(String one, String two=string.Empty, String Three=string.Empty){
dosomething
}
getAllSongs("tada");
```

But alternatively, You may use Pattern

```
    public void getAllSongs(String one, String two, String Three){
        dosomething
        }
    public void getAllSongs(String one, String two){
        getAllSongs(one,two,"");
        }
    public void getAllSongs(String one){
        getAllSongs(one,"","");
        }
        getAllSongs("tada");
```

Comment: It is in pattern i would use it, but i was lazy and tried to find if there was a way to make only one.
but it seems i have to work :)

Answer (score 6):

A different approach would be to write you code like

```
public void getAllSongs(String... songs){
    for(String song : songs){
       //do somethihg
    }
}
```

This way you can call your code like

```
getAllSongs("song");
getAllSongs("song1", "song2"......)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Method overloading:

```
public void getAllSongs(String one ){
  getAllSongs(one,null,null);
}

public void getAllSongs(String one, String two, String Three){
dosomething
}
getAllSongs("tada");
```

Answer (score 2):

it possible to call a method with a variable number of arguments like this

```
public void getAllSongs(String ... songs)
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly what you want to ask.
But i think it should be

```
    public void getAllSongs(String... number) {
    // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Overload the same method with different number of arguments, like this:

```
public void getAllSongs(String arg1) {
    getAllSongs(arg1, "default arg2", "default arg3");
}

public void getAllSongs(String arg1, String arg2) {
    getAllSongs(arg1, arg2, "default arg3");
}

public void getAllSongs(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {
    // do stuff with args
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can, it's called **Polymorphism** Or more specificly it is **Method Overloading**:

In Java, it is possible to define two or more methods of same name in a class, provided that there argument list or parameters are different. This concept is known as Method Overloading.

Take a look at the [**Polymorphism in Java – Method Overloading and Overriding**](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/polymorphism-in-java/).

Example:

```
void demo (int a) {
   System.out.println ("a: " + a);
}
void demo (int a, int b) {
   System.out.println ("a and b: " + a + "," + b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using (overloading) the method with a different number of input values. The user can call the one with just one/two/three... values. This one calles the one with more values if necessary. It could be something like this:

```
public void getAllSongs(String one){
  getAllSongs(one, null, null)
}

public void getAllSongs(String one, String two){
  getAllSongs(one, two, null)
}

public void getAllSongs(String one, String two, String Three){
dosomething
}
```

A call could be:

```
getAllSongs("bla","blub");
```

Another possibility by using arrays:

```
public void getAllSongs(ArrayList<String> songs){ 
do something 
}; 

List<String> songs= new ArrayList<String>();
songs.add("bla");
songs.add("blub");
getAllSongs(songs);
```

The ArrayList is an aarray with a dynamically size dependent on the number of values in it. Within your function you can iterate about this array

Comment: Another possibility is using an array which contains the titles of the songs. With the help of this you can use a dynamically number of songs

Comment: That's basically what varargs does under the hood, it just allows you to skip manually creating the array